# Magento 2 - Where to find LESS Mixin definition?

Tags: magento2, less, magento2.3.4

In the file **vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\css\source_breadcrumbs.less** there is this code getting called:

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .breadcrumbs {
        .lib-breadcrumbs();
    }
}
```

Lets say the mixin **.lib-breadcrumbs()** is defined multiple times in different files. How can I figure out where the mixin which is called is located? Is there a stacktrace or something which I can look into?

Comment: Just run search in your IDE or in command line grep -rnw '/var/www/html/magento' -e 'lib-breadcrumbs' to find all definition of mixin. Check is there any module overwrite or theme.

Comment: I already know this, but is this really the best way? Isn't there a stacktrace or log?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can check this library that is used for compilation of less files in Magento , maybe you will find something https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php.

Answer (score 0):

Below file

> vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/lib/_breadcrumbs.less

Comment: And what if I another module has overriden it? How do I know which one is getting used?

Comment: just type: find vendor/ -name _breadcrumbs.less

Comment: Can you explain how this command will help to identify the mixin which is called?

Comment: with this command you will find each file which possibly overrides lib-breadcrumbs.

Comment: I know, but for example in javascript I can see a stacktrace which shows me exactly where the method is located. Is there something similar in LESS? Maybe a logfile?

Comment: I expected a general answer which shows the required steps to locate the mixin. Im not just talking about the **lib-breadcrumbs()** mixin.

Answer (score -1):

magento_root/lib/web/css/source/lib/_breadcrumbs.less
This is the place where mixin defined